# Image resize adds black bars instead of transparent

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-images

I'm trying to resize my product images so they all fit in a 1:1 square. To prevent cutting off the edges I want to add whitespace, but it adds black bars instead of transparent ones. My code:

```
$image->quality(90);
$image->keepAspectRatio(true);
$image->keepFrame(true);
$image->keepTransparency(true);

if($height == $width) {
    $image->resize(1000, 1000);
}

$image->save($cachedImagePath);
```

However, it turns out like this:

[image: image with black bars]
Any ideas on how to change the black bars to white? I'm running 1.9.0.1 with the latest patches installed (up to 9767). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$image->constrainOnly(false);
$image->keepFrame(true);
// avoid black borders by setting background colour
$image->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255));
$image->keepAspectRatio(true);
$image->resize(1000, 1000);
```

Hope it will help... use `backgroundColor` to remove black color

Comment: what if we need another color? what value we need to change in that backgroundColor(array(255,255,255)) ? Thanks

Comment: Search on Google for **HEX to RGB**. It will give you RGB color code.