# Magento 2: how to set background color for product photo

Tags: magento2

anyone know how or it is possible to set background color for product photo?

example when I added clean product photo then final I want after save magento display (now display on white bg):
[image]

@ Kalyan Chakravarthi V

Now when I added product with image and save then display on white background:
[image]

I want after add product with image (*background transparent or white*) and save then display on website with an automatic background (grey) added by magento.

example:
[image]

@update code theme.less

```
.label,
label {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 9px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: inherit;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #c1c1c1
}

:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #c1c1c1
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #c1c1c1
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #c1c1c1
}
.gallery-placeholder {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: You mean you want the image to be transparent?

Comment: @ Kalyan Chakravarthi V I updated my topic.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189526/image-resize-adds-black-bars-instead-of-transparent/189527#189527

Comment: @Abhishek thanks for your comment. I hope this link topic you sent help me but which file I should edit?

Comment: You want to change it on Product detail page or everwhere?

Comment: everywhere, and also for "deals of the day".

Comment: Can you give any URL to the page? It will help us to understand more about the problem. It could be because of CSS also.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your **_theme.less**

> app/YourVendor/YourTheme/web/css/source/_theme.less

```
.gallery-placeholder {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

but I check your website you load images with background

For your theme:
I tried and swap image to transparent one and this worked for me on your page on product page.

```
img.img-responsive {
    background-color: red;
}
```

this one for carusel

```
img.img-responsive.product-image-photo.img-thumbnail.owl-lazy {background-color:red;}
```

for Deal of the day

```
img.img-responsive.product-image-photo.img-thumbnail {
    background-color: red;
}

.products-grid .product-item-info .product-top a.photo {background-color:red;}
```

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: In main topic I show you code theme.less. Also I have deleted pub/static/frontend/*  unfortunately it still does not work :(

Comment: Thanks for update and try help me. Please check: accessories-men/sunglasses-men.html I try  add after update code for deal of the day and normal product but no result :((

Comment: .product-top { background-color: red; }  and on product page .xxx.product.media { background-color: red; }